# ElasticSearch : Search_as_you_type field, how does it tokenize?

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, shingles

I am reading the official doc at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-as-you-type.html
and I do not understant how the search_as_you_type field works.

If have the following setting :

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "tokenizer": {
         "ngrams": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 10
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "partial_words" : {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "ngrams",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
   "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_text": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "shingles": { 
            "type": "search_as_you_type",
            "analyzer": "partial_words",
            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
          },
          "ngrams": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "partial_words",
            "search_analyzer": "standard",
            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to know how the my.text.shingles is tokenized.
For instance, the text

```
"Martin Luther was a german priest"
```

is analyzed at the index time in the "my_text" field with the analyzer "partial_words"
How does it work in the shingles fields ?
**Which tokens should I have in**

```
1) my_text.shingles
2) my_text.shingles._2gram
3) my_text.shingles._3gram
```

Thanks for your light !

EDIT : is there any way to be sure (or any query) to know that the _ngram fields are giving those tokens ?

```
1) my_text.shingles
[Martin, Luther, was, a, german, priest]

2) my_text.shingles._2gram
[Martin Luther, Luther was, was a, a german, german priest]

3) my_text.shingles._3gram
[Martin Luther was, Luther was a, was a german, a german priest]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this](https://coralogix.com/blog/elasticsearch-autocomplete-with-search-as-you-type/) article to understand more. Simply it's tokenizing the words like the following image.

[image]

You can use [_analyze](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) API to see how the text is tokenized.

```
POST test_search_as_you_type2/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "partial_words",
  "text": ["Martin Luther was a german priest"]
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Do you know which is the query to get the example output : ["star","wars","episode","vii","the","force","awakens"] ? thanks

Comment: Hi, You're welcome toch. it's the standard analyzer, 

`GET /_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : ""Martin Luther was a german priest""
}`